# Oracle SQL Query optional parameters performance

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, where-clause, option-type

I have a use case for performing a query on multiple optional parameters. A few parameters may or may not be passed during the query execution.

So far I have come up with two different solutions. I need some help on figuring out which performs better? Or is there any other alternate solution?

```
user_passed_variable IS NULL OR SOME_COLUMN = user_passed_variable

NVL(SOME_COLUMN, ’null’) = NVL(user_passed_variable, NVL(SOME_COLUMN, ’null’))
```

*Note*: The column can also hold null values.

Comment: Not enough detail here, but applying a function to a table column, like NVL(SOME_COLUMN) may limit the optimizer.  In that case, you can create a function-based index.  Since we don't know that your table looks like, and what indexes you have, etc.,  cannot offer much help

Comment: Having two conditions separated by `OR` will impede the use of an index on `SOME_COLUMN`. So will the function calls (and it is not clear how a function-based index would help, since `NVL(SOME_COLUMN, 'null')` is also buried within another `NVL()` call). There may be solutions that allow the use of an index. For example, if I wanted to select rows from `EMP` where `EMPNO = <user input>` or `<user input> is NULL`: `select * from EMP where <user input> is null UNION ALL select * from EMP where EMPNO = <user input>`

Comment: In this example, if the user input is `NULL` then the first member of `UNION ALL` retrieves everything while the second member is immediately recognized as empty. If the input is not `NULL` then the first member is recognized immediately as empty, and the second member can take advantage of an index on `EMPNO`.

Comment: http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I do the following :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = NVL(user_passed_variable,SOME_COLUMN);
```

If The `user_passed_variable` is NULL, It retrieves all rows and if `user_passed_variable` is set, it will fetch only the given row using the index

Works if your `SOME_COLUMN` doesn't have null values

Answer (score 0):

The filter query should work in way that if the user provided the optional value add it to a filter else don't add it to  filter so the query should check only if the user passed values are matching with the db values

```
Select * from Filter_table where 
(user_passed_value1 is null or column1 = user_passed_value1) and 
(user_passed_value2 is null or column2 = user_passed_value2)
```

so using this type of query you are searching the table based on the input given by user.